# hiding maya python plugin files

Tags: python, plugins, maya

I'm developing a maya scripted plugin that contains multiple nodes. For convenience I have split each node into a separate file like so

```
plug-ins
   |----- main_plugin.py
   |----- plugin_node_1.py
   |----- plugin_node_2.py
```

Currently I have set the plugin up so you just enable `main_plugin.py` and the others are then loaded automatically. This is ok but un-tidy as all the other plugins are paying about cluttering the plugin manager.

Other than rolling all the plugin files into one file whats the best way to clean this up a bit. Is there a way to mask some plugins from the plugin manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked out that all you need for the main_plugin.py file is an `initializePlugin(obj)` and an `uninitializePlugin(obj)` function definition. Then you can call import and initialise any other plugin files from anywhere in the python PATH like so:

```
def initializePlugin(obj):
    try:
        import plugin_node_1
        plugin_node_1.initializePlugin(obj)

        import plugin_node_2
        plugin_node_2.initializePlugin(obj)


    except: 
        print 'Failed to register plug-in'

    ms_menu.createMenu()
    ms_menu.buildMenu()


def uninitializePlugin(obj):
    try:
        import plugin_node_1
        plugin_node_1.uninitializePlugin(obj)

        import plugin_node_2
        plugin_node_2.uninitializePlugin(obj)


    except: 
        print 'Failed to deregister plug-in'

    ms_menu.deleteMenu()
```

Comment: What your doing will work but you should use with caution. You can't control the state of multiple files as easily as you can control the state of one; if node_1  loads the wrong version of node_2, you can get crashes or other problems which are not reproducible on different machines. It's safer to treat each plugin as a completely atomic unit - which , unfortunately, means that single files are a more sustainable long term solution

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'm unsure of whether to mark my answer as correct or not now

Comment: @theodox couldn't you use egg files as a some kind of intermediate complexity between the two options. Mitigating some of the problems but not addressing all of them?

Comment: That might work. I've never tried to see if zips work -- they do for regular python so it's worth a shot....